# Fuel filter location for the Chevy Malibu 2013? Replacement?

Tags: chevrolet, malibu, fuel-filter

Where's the fuel filter located in a Chevy Malibu 2013? I can't find any free info about it online (might pay for one of those services like alldatadiy), but message boards speculate it's integrated within the fuel pump inside the gas tank -  is that correct?  Considering this trend in newer cars, I wouldn't be surprised.

Also, I'm curious if it's worthwhile having it replaced since my Malibu 2013 is coming up to the 100k mark. I can't imagine a filter (or even a "lifetime filter") allowing the same flow after so many miles.

Comment: Which engine do you have? I'm thinking the fuel filter is built into the pump as you are suggesting.

Comment: The regular LT 2.5-liter engine.  Yeah that's the only part that comes up everywhere when searching for the fuel filter - but strangely no specifications of the filter within.

Comment: Here's the thing I've told many people in your situation: *Don't look for trouble where there isn't any.* Another statement I've used is: *Don't fix it if it ain't broke.* You haven't described there to actually be an issue with fuel delivery, so I'm wondering why you're worried about the filter in the first place. I know you have some mileage, but really, unless it exhibits issues, don't worry about it. One key to fuel starvation is you'll get reduced power at higher RPM levels and the ECU may throw a random misfire code when accelerating. You can always test fuel pressure as well.

Comment: Thanks, that's reassuring to know.  I was curious if preventative maintenance was going to be necessary for the fuel filter, but it does appear that the primary consensus for newer Malibus (after 2004 it appears) is to not perform mechanical preventative maintenance on the fuel system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most modern cars, the filter is located inside the pump assembly in the fuel tank.  To my knowledge, you'd have to go aftermarket to purchase the filter element only; they are all "pump assemblies," these days.   With modern gas and modern fuel tank/lines, there just isn't that much rust or debris in fuel anymore.

Unless you are having symptoms or have low pressure at the rail, the built in filter is probably doing fine.